# Getting and setting single bits in a byte-array using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, byte, bit, masking

I have a byte array with 512 Elements and need to get and set a single bit of a byte in this array.

The operation must not change any other bits, only the specified one.

So if I have a byte like &B00110011 and would like to change the third bit to 1 it should be &B00110111.

Like this:

Dim myarray(511) as byte

myarray(3).2 = 1  ---> This would change the third bit (start counting at 0) of the third byte to 1

I know it should be easily possible using bit-masking but I don't have the time to try for days to get it working.

Thanks for help!!!

Jan

Answer (score 6):

A simple way to do this is using shifts. If you want to set the Nth bit of a number to 1:

```
mask = 1 << n ' if n is 3, mask results in 00001000
bytevalue = bytevalue or mask
```

To set a bit as 0:

```
mask = 255 - (1 << n) ' if n is 3, mask results in 11110111
bytevalue = bytevalue and mask
```

In both examples, `bytevalue` is the byte in which you want to alter and `mask` is also a byte.

EDIT: To retrieve the state of a bit easily is a lot like setting a bit, Where IsSet is a boolean:

```
mask = 1 << n ' just as above
IsSet = (bytevalue and mask) <> 0
```

Comment: Thanks, this sounds easy. And how to GET the state easily?

Comment: The function to get the state is not right. ... !=0 is not possible in vb.net. Using <> 0 returns -1 on a bit that is set. Would you please correct it.

Comment: @user831915: sorry, I don't work in VB at all anymore. I detest the language, but bitmasks and such are a fun subject to talk about.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the [BitArray class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx)?

Comment: You could, but the values are not single bit.